# udp transactions between two computers

Tags: c, udp

I am working on an underwater ROV.  The ROV and the control unit on the surface each contain a        Raspberry Pi.  Control signals are sent to the ROV via a 100m fiber optic cable.  The ROV returns environmental data and video.

I choose udp as an easy way to pass simple ascii messages back and forth between the control unit and the ROV.  I found several examples of client and server code I adapted into my code.  As long as I run both client and server on the same raspberry pi, the programs communicate flawlessly.

My problem is when the client and server are on different raspberry pi.  Each RPi has its own router which hands out dhcp ip addresses - one in the range of 10.0.10.151 - 10.0.10.155 and the other 10.0.10.161 - 10.0.10.165.  There is no communication between the RPis.  I have also tried it with both RPis connected to the same router, with no luck.

I am using the ethernet port from each RPi for communication to each other.  The wifi wan on each RPi was being used by me for VNC to each RPi for testing purposes.  They are running with IP addresses in the subnet of 10.0.0.xxx. I have turned the wifi off to exclude IP traffic inference.
The udp programs have different inet_addr addresses, but I am only running 1 port per machine - which I think may be the problem.  I have not found a clear example of how to use two ports.

I have tried examples from GeektoGeek and Scaler.com.  The one I liked the best is from programminglogic.com.  Here is the code:

```
/************ UDP SERVER CODE *******************/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <inttypes.h>  
#include <arpa/inet.h>

int main(){
    int udpSocket, nBytes;
    char buffer[1024];
    struct sockaddr_in serverAddr, clientAddr;
    struct sockaddr_storage serverStorage;
    socklen_t addr_size, client_addr_size;
    int i;

    /*Create UDP socket*/
    udpSocket = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);

    /*Configure settings in address struct*/
    serverAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serverAddr.sin_port = htons(7891);
    serverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("10.0.10.170");
    memset(serverAddr.sin_zero, '\0', sizeof serverAddr.sin_zero);  `

    /*Bind socket with address struct*/
    bind(udpSocket, (struct sockaddr *) &serverAddr, sizeof(serverAddr));

    /*Initialize size variable to be used later on*/
    addr_size = sizeof serverStorage;

    while(1){
        /* Try to receive any incoming UDP datagram. Address and port of 
        requesting client will be stored on serverStorage variable */
        nBytes = recvfrom(udpSocket,buffer,1024,0,(struct sockaddr *)&serverStorage, &addr_size);

         /*Send message back to client, using serverStorage as the address*/
        sendto(udpSocket,buffer,nBytes,0,(struct sockaddr *)&serverStorage,addr_size);
        }

    return 0;
}

/************* UDP CLIENT CODE *******************/

`#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>    
#include <arpa/inet.h>

int main(){
    int clientSocket, portNum, nBytes;
    char buffer[1024];
    struct sockaddr_in serverAddr;
    socklen_t addr_size;

    /*Create UDP socket*/
    clientSocket = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);

    /*Configure settings in address struct*/
    serverAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serverAddr.sin_port = htons(7891);
    serverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("10.0.10.172");
    memset(serverAddr.sin_zero, '\0', sizeof serverAddr.sin_zero);  

     /*Initialize size variable to be used later on*/
     addr_size = sizeof serverAddr;

    while(1){
        printf("Type a sentence to send to server:\n");
        fgets(buffer,1024,stdin);
        printf("You typed: %s",buffer);

        nBytes = strlen(buffer) + 1;
    
        /*Send message to server*/
        sendto(clientSocket,buffer,nBytes,0,(struct sockaddr *)&serverAddr,addr_size);

        /*Receive message from server*/
        nBytes = recvfrom(clientSocket,buffer,1024,0,NULL, NULL);

        printf("Received from server: %s\n",buffer);

        }

        return 0;
}
```

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong when trying to use udp between to computers?
Kind regards,
David

David V. Fansler

YouTube "Sailing Solo at 70"

Solo sailed from Greece to North Caroline 2022

Comment: Start with your own server and client excluded from the equation. Can you ping one board from the other? If not, you have a basic network setup problem.

Comment: Your code uses IP addresses not from range you mentioned in description. Note client should send datagrams to server's address, but server should listen on its own local address (or any address). Most of such problems easily can be debugged by traffic analysis with `tcpdump`.

Comment: PS: Always check return values of functions for errors.

Comment: Don't bind to a specific IP address. Bind ti `0.0.0.0`, i.e. `INADDR_ANY`.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem I see in your code (excepted the basic connection problem) is the sockets creation.

Let's say your configuration is

- Server: `10.0.10.sss`
- Rov: `10.0.10.rov`

---

On the client, you can have :

```
/*Configure settings in address struct*/
serverAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
serverAddr.sin_port = htons(7891);
serverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("10.0.10.sss");

/*Bind socket with address struct*/
bind(udpSocket, (struct sockaddr *) &serverAddr, sizeof(serverAddr));
```

That means: "create a server on port 7891, which listen on ip `10.0.10.sss`

You could also have:

```
serverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
```

To tell the server to listen on all IP it have

---

On the client, you should just have:

```
serverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("10.0.10.sss");
```

As you noticed, the client IP address can be ignored.

Comment: Got it running!  It was a combination of problems - 1. while the addresses were different than the dhcp ranges indicated, since they were in the same subnet it was ok.

Comment: I tried pinging between the two RPi and got nothing.  Hooked them into my house Cisco router and it worked. Thanks for that one n.m.  Made changes suggested by Mathieu and the two programs started talking.  My many thanks.  And thanks to others who took the time to make a suggestion.  They all were valuable and appreciated.